# How to store JWT in browser?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, jwt

I'm using JSON Web Tokens (JWT) for the first time. I'm making a Node.js app using Hydra-Express framework. I want to use JWT for authentication. As per the docs, I'm returning the JSON token to the front-end.

```js
var tokenData = {
    username: req.body.username,
};

var result = {
    username: req.body.username,
    token: jwt.sign(tokenData, 'secret', { expiresIn: 60 * 60 })
};

res.json(result);
```

But I don't know how to save this JSON token to my browser header so that it doesn't get lost and is again sent to the back-end along with the header.
How to save it in my browser storage and add it to the request header each time a request is sent to the backend?

Comment: You can use cookies, localStorage, even WebSQL if you want, any browser storage would do I guess. Still, I'd suggest you read this article: http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/

Answer (score 6):

Security advice:

Trying to keep it short:
cookies(http-only & secure flag) are vulnerable to CSRF but not XSS.
JWT in localstorage is vulnerable to XSS but not CSRF

The best you can do is to minimize the risk:
store the JWT in a cookie
store a csrf_token in localstorage

To make it stateless:
Include the csrf_token in the JWT payload and check serverside if the JWT csrf_token and the csrf_token read from localstorage and provided in the header match.

This requires an attacker to get the csrf_token through XSS (e.g. you use a compromised 3rd party js library in your site or do not apply sanitation)
And then he needs to trigger a csrf request with the csrf_token (e.g. embedded img src tag or form in a webpage /email)

This combination makes it a lot harder for an attacker (but not impossible).

It provides the same security level as a normal session based authentication with csrf_tokens, but does not require state.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes back store you entire token in sessionStorage

```
sessionStorage.token = json.access_token;
```

To access the payload split the jwt token into its header.payload.signature parts and grab just the payload

```
var enc = json.access_token.split(".")[1];
```

Then parse the base64

```
var payload = JSON.parse(window.atob(enc));
```

Then you can grab and use your verified payload data
payload.sub, payload.role ...etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use **HTML5 web storage** or **cookie** to store your JWT token and read from it whenever you want to send your request to web API.

This  [link](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage) will help you decide the best match for your app.

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Building on Chris's answer:

1. **JWTs should never be stored in your localStorage**
2. In fact, they **shouldn't even be stored in your cookies**, *unless you are able to implement very strict CSRF protection*

[Checkout this for motivation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982945/how-to-store-session-id-securely#comment99797460_44982992)

- JWT as an id_token is like your user credentials
- JWT as an access_token is like your session token

The most secure option is in-memory. [Checkout this for a deep dive](https://mannharleen.github.io/2020-03-19-handling-jwt-securely-part-1/)