# How to store jwt token in localStorage and send it back to the server with header in express?

Tags: express, jwt

I have read many articles in stackoverflow and have seen lots of youtube videos, but failed to find the example code which is demonstrating about the flow of *saving jwt to localstorage - send back to server with authorization header for verifying*.

Here is what I want to do.

When the client logs in to the server, server gives token and saves it to the client `localStorage` (or `sessionStorage`).

Whenever the client calls an api which can be accessed only with the token,
client retrieves the token back from the `localStorage`, and send that token with the authorization header (`req.headers.[x-access-token]` or `req.headers.[authorization]`) to the server.

But all of the articles I've been read is explaining this issue with the Postman which does not show how to store it to the `localStorage` and put it in the authorization header.

Do I have to use `localStorage.setItem` when the server gives the token to the client, and use and `localStorage.getItem` and `new Headers()` with `append()` or `axios` before sending that token back to the server?

Examples don't have to be for the express user, but I'd like to get the glimpse of ideas.

Comment: i had so much trouble finding this question, world is so abstract

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can store your jwt token in localstorage and when ever you make a API call you can add the token to headers as token. if you are using axios you can attach you token to headers like this. Here the token is stored in localstorage with the key 'jwtToken'

```
  axios.post('http://yourendpoint',data,{ headers: { Authorization:localStorage.getItem('jwtToken') } })
            .then(response=> console.log(response))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
   };
```

Comment: is this secure?

Answer (score 5):

it's easy just Follow me

---

First of all you have to save the Token(or access token) to the local storage,
in the login component when you are sending request for login do the below:

```
signin:function() {
        axios.post('http://Somthing/log-in/',{
            username: this.username,
            password: this.password,
        })
        .then( (response) => {
            
            let token = response.data.access;
            localStorage.setItem("SavedToken", 'Bearer ' + token);
            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
            (this.$router.push({name:'HomePage'}));
            
            })
```

So now the problem is whenever you refresh the Homepage you got 401 error and the solution is : just add this :
`{ headers: { Authorization:localStorage.getItem('SavedToken') }}`
to the end of each request that need the Token in its header, like below:

```
 axios.get('http://Something/', { headers: { Authorization:localStorage.getItem('SavedToken') }})
        .then(response =>{
            //something
        })
```

Notice that the token that i used in this explanation was **SIMPLEJWT** , if you are using somthing else maybe you have to change  **'Bearer'** to somthing else.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to create or Generate Token through Jwt (jsonWebTokens) then either store it in local Storage or through Cookie or through Session. I generally prefer local storage because it is easier to store token in local storage through SET and retrieve it using GET method. and after retrieving it through get you can verify it through jwt and also authenticate it with bearer authentication..

And for headers add Authorization

```
fetch("/users", {
  method: "Get",
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    Authorization: "Bearer" + localStorage.getItem("token")
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. **JWTs should never be stored in your localStorage**
2. In fact, they **shouldn't even be stored in your cookies**, *unless you are able to implement very strict CSRF protection*

[Checkout this for motivation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982945/how-to-store-session-id-securely#comment99797460_44982992)

- JWT as an id_token is like your user credentials
- JWT as an access_token is like your session token

One option is in-memory. [Checkout this for a deep dive](https://mannharleen.github.io/2020-03-19-handling-jwt-securely-part-1/)

Comment: in memory is not secure. If you can access localstorage from javascript, you can definitely access any in memory object so the cookies approach with 'same-site' I believe to be the best. However the development might be more painful since I don't know how well does postman cope with setting cookies across requests

Comment: In-memory must be of course secured by encapsulation, the ability to have that implementation makes it secure.

Comment: JS doesn't have private fields so there is no encapsulation. Sure ES2019 has that but it lacks browser support from many providers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields . If you go the Typescript way you do have private but that is also transpiled down to normal JS so the fields might still become available